# knockout.js How to access $index in handler function

Tags: knockout.js

As I understand, `$index` is available inside a `foreach:` binding, giving the index of the object... I have a `click:` binding e.g. `click:foo` , I need to to access `$index` inside `foo`.

**Is there a way?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes,

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { myClickHandler($index, data, event); }"/>
```

Comment: I agree the default handler for clicks, blurs and so on should pass more info instead of just data and event. I use a custom binding myself if the quick cheat above doesn't fit well into the solution.

Answer (score 43):

Rather than hacking around it through a function within your binding, you just need to get the binding context.  As long as you have access to the DOM element associated with the binding, you can get the binding context and all its properties using the `ko.contextFor()` function.

The event object you get in your handler gives you access to the node through the `target` property.  Grab the context using that.

```
var viewModel = {
    foo: function (data, event) {
        var context = ko.contextFor(event.target);
        // do stuff with context.$index()
    }
};
```

Comment: Since `$index` is an observable, I had to do `context.$index()` with the parentheses, since observables are functions in knockout http://goo.gl/TIGYV1

Answer (score 0):

It is easier with ES6 code.  In my html I have an array of pages

```
<span data-bind="foreach: pages">
     <a data-bind="click: $parent.gotoPage.bind($parent), text: $index()+1">
     </a>
</span>
```

In the view controller class I have the `gotoPage` method.  The first parameter will be the $index of the `foreach`.  Very simple.

```
class ViewModel {
    constructor() {
        this.requestedPage = ko.observable(0);
        this.pages = ko.observableArray([0,1,2,3]);
    }

    async run() {
        this.message("Running");
    }

    gotoPage(pageRequested, event) {
        this.requestedPage(pageRequested);
        this.run();
    }
}
```